# A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Below is my dynamic query and it's not working.

It threw:

> A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 2.

Original dynamic query:

```
SET @QueryVendorName = ';WITH 
cteForPriceVen AS (select AI.ItemID, AI.ItemPartNumber as ItemPartNumber, AI.ItemDescription, cteForPrice.VendorPrice as Price, cteForPrice.UpdatedDate as UpdatedDate, cteForPrice.IsLocked as IsLocked
from AerospaceItems (nolock) AI
inner join VendorItemPricing (nolock) cteForPrice
on AI.ItemPartNumber = cteForPrice.ItemPartNumber where cteForPrice.VendorName = ''' + @VendorName + ''' AND
cteForPrice.ObsoleteItem = ''' + cast (@ItemType as char(1)) + ''') select * from cteForPriceVen'

SET @OrderQuery = '
    WHERE (''' + cast (@Description as varchar(250)) + ''' = '''' OR cteForPriceVen.ItemDescription like ''%' + cast (@Description as varchar(250)) + '%'')
    AND (''' + cast (@PartNumber as varchar(99)) + ''' = '''' OR cteForPriceVen.ItemPartNumber like ''%' + cast (@PartNumber as varchar(99)) + '%'')
    AND (''' + cast (@PriceFrom as varchar(25)) + ''' = '''' OR Price >= ''' + cast (@PriceFrom as varchar(99)) + ''')
    AND (''' + cast (@PriceTo as varchar(25)) + ''' = '''' OR Price <= ''' + cast (@PriceTo as varchar(99)) + ''')
    AND (''' + cast (@DateFrom as varchar(25)) + ''' = '''' OR UpdatedDate >= ''' + cast (@DateFrom as varchar(99)) + ''')
    AND (''' + cast (@DateTo as varchar(25)) + ''' = '''' OR UpdatedDate <= ''' + cast (@DateTo as varchar(99)) + ''')

    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''ItemDescription'' AND '''+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'''= ''0'' THEN cteForPriceVen.ItemDescription END ASC,
    CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''ItemDescription'' AND '''+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'''= ''1'' THEN cteForPriceVen.ItemDescription END DESC,
    CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''ItemPartNumber'' AND '''+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'''= ''0'' THEN cteForPriceVen.ItemPartNumber END ASC,
    CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''ItemPartNumber'' AND '''+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'''= ''1'' THEN cteForPriceVen.ItemPartNumber END DESC,
    CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''Price'' AND '''+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'''= ''0'' THEN Price END ASC,
    CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''Price'' AND '''+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'''= ''1'' THEN Price END DESC,
    CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''UpdatedDate'' AND '''+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'''= ''0'' THEN UpdatedDate END ASC,
    CASE WHEN '''+ @OrderBy +'''=''UpdatedDate'' AND '''+ cast (@OrderMode as varchar(10)) +'''= ''1'' THEN UpdatedDate END DESC'
```

Extracted Query:

```
;WITH 
cteForPriceVen AS (select AI.ItemID, AI.ItemPartNumber as ItemPartNumber, AI.ItemDescription, cteForPrice.VendorPrice as Price, cteForPrice.UpdatedDate as UpdatedDate, cteForPrice.IsLocked as IsLocked
from AerospaceItems (nolock) AI
inner join VendorItemPricing (nolock) cteForPrice
on AI.ItemPartNumber = cteForPrice.ItemPartNumber where cteForPrice.VendorName = 'Apple' AND
cteForPrice.ObsoleteItem = '0') select * from cteForPriceVen
    WHERE ('' = '' OR cteForPriceVen.ItemDescription like '%%')
    AND ('' = '' OR cteForPriceVen.ItemPartNumber like '%%')
    AND ('' = '' OR Price >= '')
    AND ('' = '' OR Price <= '')
    AND ('' = '' OR UpdatedDate >= '')
    AND ('' = '' OR UpdatedDate <= '')

    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN 'ItemDescription'='ItemDescription' AND '0'= '0' THEN cteForPriceVen.ItemDescription END ASC,
    CASE WHEN 'ItemDescription'='ItemDescription' AND '0'= '1' THEN cteForPriceVen.ItemDescription END DESC
```

If I remove second order by line, `CASE WHEN 'ItemDescription'='ItemDescription' AND '0'= '1' THEN cteForPriceVen.ItemDescription END DESC`  the query seems working.

Comment: `'ItemDescription'='ItemDescription'` and `'0'= '0'`will always be true, `'0'= '1'` will always be false. I think you should do something like `ItemDescription='ItemDescription'` instead.

Comment: Two issues here. Your case expressions are using strings instead of the columns. Also, why the NOLOCK hints? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate rows? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second line:

```
CASE WHEN 'ItemDescription'='ItemDescription' AND '0'= '1' THEN cteForPriceVen.ItemDescription END DESC
```

Is equivalent to `NULL`. You can't order something by `NULL`.

#### edit

If this statement is being generated by a dynamic query, what you need to do is fix the way you build the dynamic query:

```
@orderQuery = ' ORDER BY '
IF @OrderBy = 'ItemDescription'
BEGIN
  orderQuery += ' cteForPriceVen.ItemDescription '
  orderQuery += CASE WHEN @OrderMode = 1 THEN 'ASC' ELSE 'DESC' END
END
```

Comment: Upvoting as the most accurate answer.  But at the same time, I don't think it will help OP understand what he's doing wrong. Clearly his problem goes beyond this simple technicality.

Comment: First you need to explain us what you are trying to do, I mean, how do you want to sort your query?

Comment: @JoaoLeal Sorting depends on these two parameters, OrderBy and OrderMode. If OrderMode is 0, ascending else descending sort. OrderBy is the column name, such as what column should be sorted. I hope I explained what I want actually.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie the query you posted is the result of a dynamic query? If so can you put the original dynamic statement?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie check my edit, you should repeat the If statement for each of your case statements.

Answer (score 0):

This line just doesn't make sense:

```
CASE WHEN 'ItemDescription'='ItemDescription' AND '0'= '0'
```

shouldn't it be something like:

```
CASE WHEN variableName = 'Value' ...
```